# Add text next to icon

Tags: html

How can I insert a text right to the icon (see picture)?

I have this code which ads a facebook icon:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 follow"> 
   <ul class="social">
     <li>
     <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com" ><i class="fa
 fa-facebook"></i></a>
     </li> 
   </ul> 
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking at this http://jsfiddle.net/uf4bczoq/

Comment: I have tried that solution but the text falls under the icon unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `span` tag after the image, within the link...

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 follow ">
    <ul class="social">        
        <li>
            <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
               class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com">
               <i> class="fa fa-facebook" id="facebook-icon></i>
               <span>Your Text Here</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#facebook-icon,
#facebook-icon ~ span {display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Make sure in the CSS that the `i` and `span` are `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Well you might need to touch the CSS, because I've used font-awesome before and their icons default to inline and spans default to inline, so it should just work. If they are line-breaking then that means your width on the containing elements is forcing that or the `i` and `span` have changed defaults. You should probably include relevant CSS so we can check.

Comment: You could add an ID, or you could just target the `fa-facebook` class.

Comment: If you provided the actual html/css you are using then we can actually help you. How do I know you're implementing the suggestions correctly?

Comment: That took all of 3 seconds to figure out what your problem was, and I've already alluded to it in an earlier post. This class `col-sm-4` is restricting the width of your sidebar, so there isn't even enough room for the text to be on the same line. If you changed this you will see it work.

Comment: That worked very good thank you. Could you modify the code above and give it a special ID and refer it to the CSS so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-4 follow "> 
    <ul class="social "> 
        <li>
            <a title=""
            data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="facebook" 
            href="https://www.facebook.com" >
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                <!-- You can Place Text Here if you want it to be clickable with the link -->
            </a> Text Here - not clickable with link
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

you can place the text in two areas, inside the `<a></a>` tags or outside them. if its in the `<a>`, itll be clickable. if its outside, it will not

Comment: Tried it but the text falls below for some strange reason. This was my problem from the very begining and I cant seem to solve it haha

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div> <img src="Your link here"> </div>
<div> Your text here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div {
    float:left}
```

line can be put by using `<hr>` tag

Comment: Don't encourage people to use floats...they should be used as a last resort.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement your answer to my question, could you assist me with that?

Comment: OK do as indubitablee said. i was about to write like this And use <hr> for line ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is excellent for this. It's very widely supported now:

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="icon-and-text">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

```css
/* CSS */
.icon-and-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* to align icon and text vertically */
}
```